# How to find average of Excel column A if B(i) is TRUE and B(i-1) is FALSE?

Tags: excel, average, conditional-statements

I know the title is confusing but it was no easy task to summarize the problem in one sentence so bear with me.

I have two columns in Excel, column A contains real numbers, column B contains Boolean values of either TRUE or FALSE. I want to get the average of every value in column A where the corresponding cell in B is TRUE, that the cell above is FALSE.

Basically find average of all numbers in colA where [B(i) = TRUE & B(i-1) = FALSE].

Naturally you would omit the first value in colA & colB since there would be nothing to compare it to.

Comment: What about the first value `(i = 1)`, does it count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/AVERAGEIFS-function-4cca2550-dab3-41c4-bcd2-648e17f20553) should take care of this easily providing your version of Excel is 2007 or newer.

**AVERAGEIFS(**<average_range>, <criteria_range1>, <criteria1>, <criteria_range2>, <criteria2>**…)**

The size of the ranges used for *<average_range>* and one or more -<criteria_rangeX>- have to be the same but they do not have to be the same rows or columns. If you start your average range and first criteria range at the second row and offset your second criteria range back one row to the first (while keeping the same number of rows) you should receive the results you are looking for.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A2:A100, B2:B100, TRUE, B1:B99, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a start with this code:

```
Sub Average()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim nbr As Double
    Set r = Selection
    For Each cell In r.Cells
    If CBool(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) And Not CBool(cell.Offset(-1, 1).Value) Then
    sum = sum + cell.Value
    nbr = nbr + 1
    End If
    Next
    av = sum / nbr
    MsgBox ("Your average is " & av)
    End Sub
```

Pre-conditions:

- You need to have your range of value selected.
- Make sure that there is a row above your selection so the offset functions correctly
- Add a condition to to handle nbr when it equals to zero

End result:

[image]